# Why are the op-amps' positive inputs getting biased to -3.8 V in this differential probe circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, bias, differential-amplifier

My students built a differential probe circuit, basically following [this circuit](https://hackaday.io/project/169390-a-10x-100mhz-differential-probe) from Hackaday shown below:

[image]

For U1 and U2 they instead used [MAX4104](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX4104-MAX4305.pdf)ESA+ op-amps. The op-amps are supplied through +/-5 V linear regulators (7805 and 7905) from two 9 V block batteries. R23 and R24 were not included in their circuit.

When turning the circuit on, a constant -3.8 V appears on both op-amps' (U1.1 and U1.2) non-inverting inputs and that voltage stays constant, no matter what we apply on the voltage divider input.

Say we apply 9 V on J1+ and GND on J1-. The voltage at both op-amps' non-inverting inputs stays at -3.8 V, the voltage from J1+ to GND is 10 V, and the voltage across the upper part of the voltage divider (R2 to R5) now is 12.8 V. Setting the negative supply rail of the op-amps to 0 V pushes this bias to +2.2 V.

First I thought they might have included the wrong protection diodes D1 and D2 such that they pulled the signal to -Vcc, but desoldering them didn't change anything. The op-amps are all getting the correct voltage on the supply pins and are not drawing any excessive currents (20 mA per supply pin according to the data sheet). I also couldn't identify any errors or short-circuits on the PCB. Desoldering U1.1 caused the voltage at the non-inverting input of U1.2 to slightly change, I believe it was around -2 V. Desoldering U1.1 also, the voltage divider outputs started giving the correct attenuated voltages.

My final guess now is that the op-amps might be broken, but I am also not measuring any short-circuits or, as I said, excessive currents, and such a failure mode has never occured in any of my circuits before.

Unfortunately we do not have spares of the MAX4104 and no pin-compatible op-amps available. I'll have them fiddle in another type of op-amp today to see if we can get the circuit to work then and (hopefully) confirm, that it was indeed the op-amps.

Has anyone ever experienced such an error before or has an idea what might be causing this? Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: `R23 and R24 were not included in their circuit.` Are the resistors not mounted or simply shorted? They are in series with the non-inverting inputs, so removing them basically makes the inputs floating.

Comment: They are shorted, so the inputs are not floating.

Comment: What voltages do you measure at the (-) inputs of both op-amps, their outputs, and the input of your R2-R5 string? I know they should be floating, but in case you measure a different voltage than -3.8V, it could give a clue.

Comment: At the outputs and - Inputs I'm measuring -3.7 something Volts, which roughly coincides with the given output voltage swing.
At input of R2-R5 string I'm either measuring 0 V to GND, or whatever voltage I apply there.

Comment: @M.Matthias that seems off to me. Assuming that the -3.8V comes from the Op-amp not finding itself in it's linear operating region (i.e. the op-amp is forcing that operating point), and that resistor string, I'd expect the -3.8V should appear in either end of that string, as it seems to be floating from what your schematic shows.

Comment: @ ErnestoG I'll go check again, maybe I remembered wrong.

Comment: With J1 open, i measure -2.75 V across the voltage dividers, with J1 shorted, I measure -3.22 V across the voltage dividers.

Comment: (`across the voltage dividers` I see *loads* of voltage dividers: at the (both pairs of) clamp diodes?)

Comment: @greybeard meaning at the input, e.g. from top of R2 (or J1+) to GND

Comment: If the wiper of R11 loses contact, all bets are off: increase to the next plausible value and connect resistors from R6&R13 to GND for original resistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Has anyone ever experienced such an error before or has an idea what
> might be causing this? Am I missing something crucial?*

Take note: -

- The input bias current for the MAX4104 is a whopping 32 μA (typical).
- The bias current for the LTC6269 (described is an Ultra-Low Bias Current FET Input Op Amp in the [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/62689f.pdf)) is less than 4 pA (maximum).

That input bias current has to go somewhere and that somewhere are the resistors to the 0 volts formed by R21, R1, R6 and R11 (50% of it). That's about 41 kΩ: -

[image]

So, when 32 μA flows from the input and through 41 kΩ yoiu get a volt drop of  1.312 volts. That's the typical value you might expect so when you say this: -

> *When turning the circuit on, a constant -3.8 V appears on both
> op-amps' (U1.1 and U1.2) positive inputs*

I can believe it. This is why we do simulations before we build.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I can't believe I completely overlooked that. The resistor values on their input voltage divider are also different, and they actually chose a total combined lower side resistor of 500k. Which would give16 V, but it's saturating to the max. output voltage swing I suppose. Thanks a lot!